# How to reclaim ^S in zsh?

Tags: vim, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've found ^S mapped to be the fwd-search key for zsh (ohmyzsh) but I would like to use it in vim for various mappings as well - it seems like the zsh mapping is preventing me from using it now.

Any way to unmap the bindkey or have it both ways?

Comment: Are you sure that it's oh-my-zsh? I couldn't find anything in its sources where `bindkey` maps `Ctrl-S`.

Comment: yeah, i think it is actually default zsh - i mention ohmyzsh in case there is something there that might be important as well - i'm still new new zsh

Comment: On my system (never used zsh before) `Ctrl-S` suspends, as it should. Have you checked your zsh profile files?

Comment: i'm still digging around - hoping i could find insight here faster :-) ... previously bash for me worked out fine with C-s

Comment: To investigate zsh mappings/bindings, use `bindkey`. Use `bindkey "^S"` to see what `Ctrl-S` specifically is bound to. Look up details on the bound "widgets" with `man zshzle`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably flow-control, which is handled by your terminal and not your shell.  Typically control-s stops terminal output, and control-q resumes it.  See the note in  "`:help ctrl-s`".

To remove this behavior, you could try these shell commands:

```
stty stop undef
stty start undef
```

This may not work, though.  If you are using a GUI terminal emulator, try looking for flow control settings within its options.

Answer (score 7):

I shot it down in two steps:

1. Disabling flow control in Konsole:

   - Settings > Manage Profiles... > Edit Profile > Advanced (tab) > uncheck 'Enable Flow Control [...]')

   [image]
2. Tell Zsh about it, too:

   ```
   setopt noflowcontrol
   ```